# Issue with sending 2 dimensional array of files

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending multiple files with `formData` like this

[image: form data structure]

In my Spring MVC Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/marches")
public Integer saveMarches(
        @RequestPart("formJson") FooBean formJson, 
        @RequestPart("attachOs") MultipartFile[][] attachOs
        ) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

My conf :

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(30000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

But i got a `400 Bad Request` in the browser

[image]

And in the IDE I got :

> ```
> Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
> Required request part 'attachOs' is not present]
> ```

and if i try `@RequestPart("attachOs[][]") MultipartFile[][] attachOs` i got always a bad request with `Required request part 'attachOs[][]' is not present`

**The problem is obvious** : spring is searching just for `attachOs` part (`@RequestPart("attachOs")`) but i am sending `attachOs[0][0]`, `attachOs[0][1]` ...

When i send just the `formJson` part without files or if i send just a single file `@RequestPart("attachOs") MultipartFile attachOs` or one dimension array of files `@RequestPart("attachOs") MultipartFile[] attachOs` everything works fine.

Javascript code :

```
const formData = new FormData();

for (const [i, os] of formJson.os.entries()) {
    if(os.attachment) {
        for (const [j, file] of [...os.attachment].entries()) {
            formData.append(`attachOs[${i}][${j}]`, file );
        }
    }
}
...
formData.append('formJson', 
           new Blob([JSON.stringify(formJson)], {type:'application/json'}));
...
axios({
    url: ...,
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
})
...
```

My `formJson` structure is

```
{
    // form fields
    ...
    os: [
        {
            // os form fields
            ...
            attachment: [{ /* File type */ }, ...], // multiple files per os
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I know that files cannot be sent along with JSON that's why i am constructing the formData above and after that i will delete the attachment property from JSON structure

So my questions :

**1.** How to fix the bad request issue ?

**2.** is there another approach or design pattern to handle this use case ?

Comment: Can you first try `@RequestPart(name="attachOs", required=false)` and test that your controller can accept only `formJson` portion? Also add `consumes = "multipart/form-data"` in your `@PostMapping` annotation

Comment: I think the problem is that spring is looking for a part named `attachOs` but your form data shows part named `attachOs[0][0]`, etc.
Don't know if spring could make a research by dynamic names. But maybe the solution is that you use attachOs as entry nam for each entry? Like:
`formData.append(`attachOs`, file );`

Comment: try `@RequestPart("attachOs[][]") MultipartFile[][] attachOs` notice the square brackets in the annotation value.

Comment: How about trying with a single object, make it a `MultipartFile attachOs` with only one input from front-end with `formData.append('attachOs', file );` only once, and try to see that you can essentially get multiple request parts correctly.

Comment: @Mustafa  `@RequestPart("attachOs[][]") MultipartFile[][] attach` already try it but with no success

Comment: Also the size might still be an issue,`30000000 bytes` is just `30 megabytes`, so again might be exceeding the size... You can put `setMaxUploadSize(-1)` to make it limitless?

Comment: @Mohicane yeah that is the problem and i can't use just `formData.append(attachOs, file );` because i have to associate each file with its meta data in `formJson` part

Comment: @buræquete when i send just one file or one dimension array of files everything works fine and i send only file with small size.

Comment: @Youssef still can't you just confirm `setMaxUploadSize(-1)` is not working as well? Maybe somehow you are going above `30 megabytes` with your request? Because `attachOs[]` and `attachOs[][]` has no difference, Spring should recognize both in same manner

Comment: Maybe you could create a sub object that contains two MultipartFile to keep the connection. And then your rest-method signature becomes: `saveMarches(
        ..., @RequestPart("attachOs") YourNewObject[] attachOs)`. Then your javascript call can be written as I told before?

Comment: @Youssef do you need to send multiple files per os?

Comment: @Mustafa yes exactly

Comment: Instead of 2d array, can't you use hashmap?

Comment: @ChintanPandya can you explain how to achieve this ?

Comment: Is the first dimension starting from 0 and reaching to the end without gaps? Are all the rows starting from 0 and reaching to the end without gaps? Are all the rows having the same number of columns? Can you give us a real example of what is being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by utilizing a `@ModelAttribute` (from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload));

First create a model class like;

```
public class MyRequest {
    private FooBean formJson;
    private MultipartFile[][] attachOs = new MultipartFile[2][2];

    // getters/setters
}
```

Then add it to your controller like;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/marches", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public Integer saveMarches(@ModelAttribute MyRequest request) throws IOException {
    // some code
}
```

The important part was the initialization of the `MultipartFile[][] attachOs`, otherwise it does not work with multidimensional arrays due to some internal initialization issue.

---

Or you can use the following type in the model class;

```
private List<MultipartFile>[] attachOs;
```

which works without an initialization.

Comment: i had before the size problem and the error mention it clearly that i have a size problem so i increase it but now it's a bad request about the name of `attachOs` parameter

Comment: @Youssef I understand, but I saw some examples of size issue causing exact 400 error as yours. Since `attachOs[]` works, it is weird that `attachOs[][]` does not work. There shouldn't be a problem between those two... I am investigating your question still

Comment: Just one last thing there is a mismatch converter error with `FooBean formJson` because formJson is sent as a blob so i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'beans.FooBean ' for property 'formJson': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]`, I have fix this by separating fields, i put `@RequestPart("formJson") FooBean formJson` directly in the controller method

Comment: If you have a solution for this issue it will be great otherwise it's not a big problem maybe i will open a specific question to that issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send multiple file attachments per OS you can use a `List` instead of a 2-dimensional array in the spring controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/marches")
public Integer saveMarches(
        @RequestPart("formJson") FooBean formJson, 
        @RequestPart("attachOs") List<MultipartFile> files
        ) throws IOException {

    // Associate files with their os using the index in their name.
}
```

and in your angular code append the os index in the name of the file.

```
for (const [i, os] of formJson.os.entries()) {
    if (os.attachment) {
        for (const [j, file] of [...os.attachment].entries()) {
            formData.append(`attachOs`, file, file.name + ":" + i );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa I will run some test, i think that adding data to the file name in the 3rd argument of `append` method is a good trick

Answer (score 1):

Spring supports binding all multivalue map and single value map of multipart and part  files in [`SPR-17405`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21938)

Adding `Map<String, MultipartFile>` will map the multipart value to key.

Something like `attachOs[0][0]`, `attachs[0][1]`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/marches")
public Integer saveMarches(
        @RequestPart("formJson") FooBean formJson, 
        @RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> attachOs
        ) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Another variation would be send multiple multipart values per row. For that you could use
`MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile>`. For this variation you have to update your angular code.

Something like `attachOs[0]`, `attachs[1]`

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/marches")
    public Integer saveMarches(
            @RequestPart("formJson") FooBean formJson, 
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> attachOs
            ) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```

If you would like to use second variant you can give unique name per os and append files. There is no need to make it appear like array. You can call data.append multiple append with same name and it will add them as array of files.

```
for (const [i, os] of formJson.os.entries()) {
    if(os.attachment) {
        for (const [j, file] of [...os.attachment].entries()) {
            formData.append(os.name, file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's `Map<String, MultipartFile>` or `Map<String, MultipartFile[]>` ?

Comment: There are two variants - One is Map of single file part just like hash map. Other is Map of multivalue parts like map of linkedlist something like `Map<String,List<Multipart>>`.

Comment: If you would like to use second variant you can give unique name per os and append files. There is no need to make it appear like array. You can call data.append multiple append with same name and it will add them as array of files. Updated answer.

Comment: I have tested & verified my answer with postman. Let me know if you are running into issues.

Comment: Thanks man your answer really help me a lot even if @buræquete 's answer is more suitable for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom converter @Component, which implements HttpMessageConverter

Comment: Can you develop more your idea

Comment: I mean seems there is no default converter for your case, so perhaps you need to customize it

Comment: I use jackson to marshalling and unmarshalling JSON.